# Fluent Migrator created table Version Info in wrong DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-migrator

When I connected to SQL Server, Fluent Migrator creates a `Version Info` table in the `master` database, but I create the database myself with a SQL script, then the app drops because it can't find the `version info` table.

What do I need to do for my script to run correctly?

C# code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connString = @"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    //Migration
}

private static IServiceProvider CreateServices(string connString)
{
    return new ServiceCollection()
        // Add common FluentMigrator services
        .AddFluentMigratorCore()
        .ConfigureRunner(rb => rb
            .AddSqlServer()
            // Set the connection string
            .WithGlobalConnectionString(connString)
            // Define the assembly containing the migrations
            .ScanIn(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).For.Migrations())
        // Enable logging to console in the FluentMigrator way
        .AddLogging(lb => lb.AddFluentMigratorConsole())
        // Build the service provider
        .BuildServiceProvider(false);
}

/// <summary>
/// Update the database
/// </summary>
private static void UpdateDatabase(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    // Instantiate the runner
    runner.MigrateUp(1610594913);
    runner.MigrateUp(1610594914);
}

[Migration(1610594913, TransactionBehavior.None)]
public class Migration_1610594911 : Migration
{
    public override void Down()
    {
        Execute.Sql("DROP DATABASE siteDB");
    }

    public override void Up()
    {
        Execute.Sql(@"CREATE DATABASE siteDB;");
    }
}
```

Second SQL:

```cs
[Migration(1610594914)]
public class CreateTablesMigation : Migration
{
    public override void Down()
    {
    }

    public override void Up()
    {
        Execute.Sql(@"
USE siteDB;
CREATE TABLE[AspNetRoles]
...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the database outside of FluentMigrator, then specify the database to use, by providing a connection string parameter `Initial Catalog=xxx` or `Database=xxx` (they mean the same thing)

Creating the db is done by the same way you'd run any normal SQL, using a SqlCommand, before you run your migrations